# FBLoginButton not requesting permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

Firstly, apologies for the vague question!
At short notice I've been handed an app which has started failing when posting Facebook status updates. It seems to be using a very old version of the Facebook SDK so none of the code examples I have found work.

The error message when trying to post implies that `facebook.users.setStatus` endpoint is deprecated.
Accordingly, I updated the code to call `facebook.stream.publish` which seems to be the currently supported.

This results in a permissions error (code 200).

I then changed the Facebook app record to request the `publish_actions` permission. This looks good on the Facebook preview page:
[image]

...but doesn't seem to be reflected onthe in-app Facebook logon screen:
http://s13.postimage.org/d5sf8j0zr/i_Phone_No_Permissions_Request_Redact.png

I have waited several hours now so I don't think the problem is Facebook propogating the
app settings. Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track here?

Plan B would be rewrite Facebook access using latest Facebook SDK, but this will require an upgrade for XCode and Mac OS, which I'm keen to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The publish_actions permission is used when dealing with Open Graph actions. From what I've read you'll need the extended publish_stream permission.

Comment: Thanks. I think I read that publish_actions was preferred to publish_stream but didn't really get why.

Comment: Because publish_stream is extended permission. It's really better to reduce those as much as possible. :)

Comment: Thanks. This permission still doesn't appear to be requested when the user connects with Facebook though. Interestingly the Login Preview Dialog now makes no mention of posting on the user's behalf (despite the app now have publish_actions and publish_stream permissions assigned).

Comment: The publish_stream permission appears on 2nd screen after accepting the basic permissions. Can you confirm it's still not visible?

Comment: I get 2 Facebook screens when logging in. 'Welcome to Facebook' which asks for credentials, and then the Install / Cancel screen (shown in 2nd screen shot). After that  I am logged in, and see no further permissions requests.